# Getting Seg Fault when not Printing Statement Beforehand when implementing Queue Structure and Threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, queue, printf

I am experiencing the strangest thing. In my code, I am implementing a doubly linked list as a queue. I use this queue for threads to switch between functions. For example, the way it is meant to work is that I have some arbitrary numbers A and B. A is the number of threads and B is how many times each thread is executed. Use A = 2, and B = 3 for example. I first call a method called start_thread which starts the thread of each function. Since A = 2, I would call this twice: start_thread(funct1); start_thread(funct2);. In this method, TCB_T objects are added to my queue object. I then call run() method as seen below. The program should then alternate between funct1 and funct2 until each has run B (3) times. In each function I call yield method which essentially just switches to the next thread.

Sorry for long explanation, I have listed all methods I referred to, down below so that you can see for yourself.

So the strange error is that in my main function I have a print statement for debugging. All it does is print "here\n". When I run the program, the results are perfect and exactly what I need. However, when this print statement is removed or more specifically when the \n is removed, I get a seg fault.

I ran GDB to try to see the issue, but it tells me that the seg fault is happening in my Queue File, more specifically in the Delete method when I try to access Head->Head->next. I have taken extra precautions in both my add method and my newItem method to assure that this has memory allocated and that it is either set to Null or a TCB_T object.

I apologize for a such a thorough and elongated post for what seems like a small issue, I felt that there might be many layers to the solution so I figured it best to present all the necessary files and try to define what I am doing with them.

To recap, my program works great when a print statement is included in main, but segfaults otherwise. The segfault happens in DeleteQueue when that function is called by RotateQ. I can confirm that function1 runs once (the print statement saying what iteration it is), and then the program runs into this issue. If anyone finds a solution or has any advice on how to go about finding one, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have a memory leak when you do `tcb = (TCB_T*)malloc(sizeof(TCB_T));` followed by `tcb = NewItem();`

Comment: If adding/removing a random printf causes a segfault, it generally means you've written through an invalid pointer or outside array bounds somewhere in your program. The location of the segfault probably has very little to do with where the actual error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(stackPtr)` is not the amount of memory that was allocated with `malloc()` for `stackPtr`. It's the size of a pointer, 8 bytes in a 64-bit system.

So when you do `tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t) stack_size;` you're setting the size of the thread's stack to only 8 bytes.

That argument to `init_TCB()` should be the size of the memory area you allocated, `8192`.